# JPA Custom query Delete from multiple tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, crud

I have an custom query for delete records from 2 tables as follows

```js
@Repository
public interface RoamingStatusHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<RoamingStatusHistory, String> {
    @Query("DELETE rsh,rs from RoamingStatusHistory rsh inner join RoamingStatus rs on rsh.msisdn = rs.msisdn where TIMEDIFF(NOW(),rsh.createdDate)>'00:00:30'")
    public List<Date> deleteByDate();
}
```

But after DELETE IntelliJ saying **from expected got rsh** and after rsh there is a error saying **alias definition or WHERE expected, got ','**

How to fix this issue. Have researched in the internet but couldn't find a solution

Comment: You cannot delete from two tables. Or did you manage to do that with SQL on the database?

Comment: Yes that query working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this query is a native SQL query so you have to add nativeQuery = true

```
@Repository
public interface RoamingStatusHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<RoamingStatusHistory, String> {

    @Query("DELETE rsh,rs from RoamingStatusHistory rsh inner join RoamingStatus rs on rsh.msisdn = rs.msisdn where TIMEDIFF(NOW(),rsh.createdDate)>'00:00:30'",
           nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Date> deleteByDate();
}
```